# Property variables cannot be read?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In the header, I declare my

```
NSString *name;
```

Variable. Then I make it a property with

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *name;
```

And I synthesize it in the implementation

```
@synthesize name;
```

And, immediately, give it a value in the init method:

```
name = @"HELLO";
```

Later I add a child to my scene. This child, later, will try to access this property. It goes like

```
Battle *battleScene = (Battle*)self.parent;
NSLog(@"%@",battleScene.name);
```

But I get "null". Why is that?

Comment: NSString objects should not be retained but copied. Not sure if this fixes your problem but you should change the property modifier from retain to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason for this may be that self.parent is nil. This happens if you try to run the code in the init method of the child node.

```
CCNode* child = [[[CCNode alloc] init] autorelease];
// at this point the init method is run but parent of the child is still nil …
…

[self addChild:child];
// now the parent of the child is set, after it's been added to the hierarchy
```

If you do run this in the init method, move that code to the onEnter method instead:

```
-(id) init
{
     // self.parent == nil !!
} 

-(void) onEnter
{
    // self.parent is guaranteed to be non-nil in onEnter
    Battle *battleScene = (Battle*)self.parent;
    NSLog(@"%@",battleScene.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the **`Battle`** class define `name`? Also, are you creating an instance of `battleScene` before or after you have set **`name = @"HELLO";`**?

### For Example

```
@interface Battle : NSObject
{
    NSString *name;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *name;
@end
```

Comment: I create the instance after setting name. Also, what do you mean by "Battle class **define name**"?

Comment: Battle interface is where you need to define **name**, otherwise, `battleScene.name` will always return nil becuase name doesn't exist in **Battle**

Comment: Yes, I do have it defined then.

Answer (score -1):

```
name = @"HELLO";
```

does not set the property.

```
self.name = [NSString stringWithString:@"HELLO"];
```

will set the property for you.  It will retain the object for you and this is a good way to assign it because `[NSString stringWithString:@"HELLO"]` is autoreleased.  Using `self.name =` will release your previous name and retain the one you are setting.

You get this behavior by including `retain` in the property declaration

Comment: He's setting in in the init method, so it sets the backing store. Using `self.` in init methods is discouraged. I suspect that he is not passing a string literal as in his example, but creating a string and not retaining it.